# Mean value theorem for random variables (inside an expectation value)

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, proof-explanation

In a proof I am trying to understand a mean value theorem for random variables is used. It is stated that

$$E[f(X+Y)]=E[f(X)+f^\prime(X+\Theta Y)]$$

for real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ and $f\in C^1$ (*Note: I had to change the equation above*). The random variable $\Theta$ has values in $[0,1]$.

**My question:** It is also stated, that the random variable $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and independent of $X$ and $Y$. Why is this the case? Can you point me to the used theorem? (In my textbook only the results but not the used theorems are mentioned...)

**Additional information:**

- $X = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1, k\neq i}^n Y_k$ for standardized i.i.d random variables $Y_k$ and a certain $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
- $Y = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Y_i$
- Thus $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
- $f$ is the solution of a [Stein equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_method) for normal approximation

**Update 1:** I just found out, that it is important to take the mean on both sides of the equation. I edited my question...

**Update 2:** I found a solution for the question, why $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed (see my answer). It remains the question: Why is $\Theta$ independent of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The expectation on the inside is considered conditional on $X$ and $Y$, correct? (i.e. not just a constant wrt X and Y)

Comment: Corrected some typos in the equations, which were making them absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f$ one has:

$$\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x) &= \int_x^y f'(s) ds \\
&= (y-x) \int_0^1 f'(x+(y-x)t)dt \\
&= (y-x) E\left[f'\left(x+(y-x)\Theta\right)\right]
\end{align}$$

with $\Theta$ uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. Thus

$$\begin{align}
E[f(X+Y)]-E[f(X)] &= E[f(X+Y) - f(X)] \\[1em]
&\left\downarrow\ f(y)-f(x) = (y-x) E\left[f'\left(x+(y-x)\Theta\right)\right] \right.\\[1em]
&= E[\ Y\cdot  E[f'(X+\Theta Y)]\ ]
\end{align}$$

So

$$E[f(X+Y)] = E[f(X) + \ Y\cdot  E[f'(X+\Theta Y)]]$$

Because $\Theta$ can be freely chosen, one can chose $\Theta$ independent of $X$ and $Y$. (I didn't check it, but I guess one can always construct a random variable with a given distribution which shall be independent of other variables).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something important, but I find it quite clear. I think of  $\Theta$ simply as the moving index for the integral, and it moves through it. It takes values from 0 to 1 regardless $X$ and $Y$. As said, most probably I'm missing the point that makes you think they are dependant, but then I'd be glad if you could explain it.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans: Yeah, I think you are right...

Comment: Some expectations are faulty, for example, $$E[\ Y\cdot  E[f'(X+\Theta Y)]\ ]$$ should read $$E[\ Y\cdot  f'(X+\Theta Y)\ ]$$ and $$E[f(X+Y)] = E[f(X) + \ Y\cdot  E[f'(X+\Theta Y)]]$$
 should read $$E[f(X+Y)] = E[f(X) + \ Y\cdot  f'(X+\Theta Y)]$$
 Likewise, the mention that "Because $\Theta$ can be freely chosen, one can chose $\Theta$ independent of $X$ and $Y$" is quite faulty, actually one **must** use $\Theta$ independent of $X$ and $Y$, otherwise the whole construction breaks down.